# the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by the collection of all one-point subsets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Is my proof correct?

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be the collection of all subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that either $A$ or $A^{c}$ is countable, and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the collection of all singleton subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. It is clear that $\mathscr{B}$ is a subcollection of $\mathscr{A}$, so that the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(\mathscr{B})$ generated by $\mathscr{B}$ is contained in $\mathscr{A}$, since $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Now any $A\in \mathscr{A}$ is either countable in which case $A$ will be a member of $\sigma(\mathscr{B})$, or its complement $A^{c}$ is countable in which case $A^{c}$ will be a member of $\sigma(\mathscr{B})$,and since $\sigma$-algebras are closed under complementation it follows that $A$ will be a member of $\sigma(\mathscr{B})$. Hence $\mathscr{A}$ is a subcollection of $\sigma(\mathscr{B})$, and we conclude that $\sigma(\mathscr{B})=\mathscr{A}$.

Comment: In your argument you use the word "finite" (twice), that is incorrect. You need "countable" there.

Comment: It's not true that an element $A$ of $\mathscr A$ satisfies either $A$ is finite or $A^c$ if finite (you have to replace "finite" by "countable"). After you've done that, is that clear that a countable $A$ is in $\sigma(\mathscr B)$?

Comment: I already knew this fact, Im just absent-minded. thanks @DanielFischer

Comment: @PseudoNeo I edited my proof. yes it is clear,since $\sigma(\mathscr{B})$ contains countable unions of singeleton sets

Comment: Now, your proof is watertight! (Note that the fact that we are dealing with $\mathbb R$ has no bearing on the result: the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the points is always this countable/cocountable $\sigma$-algebra, as your proof perfectly shows...)

Comment: @PseudoNeo Yes, I did not use any property of the system of real numbers,

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is missing a very important detail, namely the fact that $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Once you have proved this your arguments are good and they can just be “streamlined”.

1. If $A\in\mathscr{A}$ is countable, it is a countable (disjoint) union of singletons; if $A\in\mathscr{A}$ and $A^c$ is countable, then $A^c$ is the countable union of singletons.

   Therefore $\mathscr{A}$ is contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the singletons.
2. Any countable union of singletons belongs to $\mathscr{A}$, so $\mathscr{A}$ contains the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the singletons.

In conclusion, once granted that $\mathscr{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, your proof is good.

Comment: I have started reading measure theory by Cohn,and that is why I did not prove that $A$ is a $\sigma-algebra$ since it has already been proved in the book.

Comment: @Milad In that case, good! But it should be mentioned, since it's a very important detail.